# Storyboard conflicting constraints for UITableViewCell while using dynamic height

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, uitableview

I have strange problem with storyboards. I'm refactoring my application code to get advantage of using automatic dimension of row height instead of UITableViewDelegate method. My cell is very simply - it has only one children which is UIView. I have added constraints:

[image]

and I have constraints conflict:
[image]

but on simulator everything works pretty well, and I don't have any constraints warning in console.

Can you tell me whats wrong? Maybe I don't get the idea of cell dynamic sizing but in my opinion I should set constraints that determine cell height without ambiguity (and my three constraints are doing it).

Comment: If the height of the UITableViewCell is not 63 the three constraints are conflicting :). You mentioned "cell dynamic sizing" so i guess the subviews height should be variable. In that case you can try and remove the height (50) constraint.

Comment: I don't want to set set explicitly height of UITableViewCell. I want to autolayout determine this value from height of views that are childrens of UITableViewCell.

Comment: I see. The conflicts displayed in storyboard might be from the setting of "Table View Cell" - height. As said above it must be 63 (if "Separator" is set to "None") else the correct value is 64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nearest neighbor to your view.bottom is 12 for the view in the cell, which is the superview.Bottom.Margin (or the content view of the cell). You are requesting the view.bottom to have a constraint of 8. Moreover to satisfy these constraints Interface builder needs to change the height of the view (the blue one in your example). this of course can't be done because there is a constraint limiting the height of the view to be 50.

To fix this so the numbers add up change the height of the table view cell to be 80 instead of the default 84. But if you intend to change the height of the table cell dynamically you may come into more constraint problems.

Or change the constraint "Vertical Space-(8)-Content View-View" to have a constant of 12. So it will be "Vertical Space-(12)-Content View-View". Again if you change the height of the table cell dynamically you will have problems.

Do you intend for the view to be centered in the table cell? if thats the case then remove the two vertical constraints and add a center y alignment constraints. Then when you change the height of the cell the view will center itself vertically by calculating what the top and bottom constraints should be.

Below is the sample project i created:

```
#import "testLayoutControllerTableViewController.h"

@interface testLayoutControllerTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *thetable;
@end

@implementation testLayoutControllerTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I would post images of the interface builder setup and how it looks in simulator but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: From where did you get value 12?

Comment: I have added y constraint as vertical center of contentView but in that case the height of row is smaller that blue view when I run it in simulator.

Comment: when you try to add a bottom constraint to the view. the suggested values are spaces to nearest neighbor. For the bottom one its suggested 12

Comment: The vertical centered constraint should be added to the blue UIView not the Content View. If you're not explicitly modifying the height of the table cell in code and all the references in Interface builder are connected properly it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The problem was the result of height of cell in storyboard. I thought the height that was set in storyboard was only for testing purpose. I have set height to 63 (50+5+8) and everything is working fine without storyboards warnings.

Comment: Shouldn't automatic cell height automatically (pun intended) work, instead of needing to specify a fixed height in the Size inspector?